# BigQuery SQL: Join two tables on String distance

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, levenshtein-distance

I'm facing a problem joining two tables in BigQuery based on two string fields.

The idea is that these two fields are supposed to contain the same data in both tables, but since they were both filled manually, it's possible that the same value could've been entered slightly differently in each table (for example I could have "J. Smith" and "John Smith").

For this reason, I'd like to join my two tables on string similarity instead of equality, like for each line in table A, joining on a few lines that could match it in table B, based on the Levenshtein distance between these fields.

I've tried to use a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.name,
    b.name,
    b.id
FROM 
    `dataset.table_a` a
LEFT JOIN 
    `dataset.table_b` b
ON
    `functions_dataset.levenshtein_distance`(a.name,b.name) > 0.9
```

But I get the following error `Subquery in join predicate should only depend on exactly one join side.`

Then I tried a `CROSS JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.name,
    b.name,
    b.id
FROM 
    `dataset.table_a` a
CROSS JOIN 
    `dataset.table_b` b
WHERE
    `functions_dataset.levenshtein_distance`(a.name,b.name) > 0.9
```

But then I get an error saying that this query is too big to be executed (I work on tables with tens/hundreds of thousands of lines)

I'm out of ideas, any suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT: The function I use for the string comparison isn't actually the Levenshtein distance, but the following :
`1 - Levenshtein_distance(string_a, string_b) / max(len(string_a), len(string_b))`, so it's kind of a "similarity ratio", not that it changes anything to the question though

Comment: I'm confused.  Levenshtein distance is an *integer*.  Any value greater than 0.9 would simply mean that the two values are not equal.  Although the question in general might be of interest, the specific question using "Levenshtein distance" is not.

Comment: Sorry I didn't precise this part, the function I use is actually 1 - Levenshtein_distance/Max(len(string_a),len(string_b)), because the Levenshtein distance isn't really relevant, I'd rather compare on "similarity ratio"